# HDInsightOndemand linked Service unable to create Cluster

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-hdinsight, azure-storage-account

I have HDInsightHive Azure Data Factory Activity which is using HDIOnDemandLinkedService, but it is giving me this below error.

[image]

I have checked blob storage account it is GeneralPurpose V1 account and on Standard Pricing, still the issue.
It was working till yesterday but from today I am unable to figure out what is the change.

Below is my HDIOnDemandLinkedService code

```
{
    "name": "HDIOnDemandLinkedService",
    "properties": {
        "hubName": "ne1admapsimplymeasureddf01_hub",
        "type": "HDInsightOnDemand",
        "typeProperties": {
            "version": "3.6",
            "clusterSize": 2,
            "timeToLive": "01:00:00",
            "osType": "Linux",
            "coreConfiguration": {},
            "hBaseConfiguration": {},
            "hdfsConfiguration": {},
            "hiveConfiguration": {},
            "mapReduceConfiguration": {},
            "oozieConfiguration": {},
            "sparkConfiguration": {},
            "stormConfiguration": {},
            "yarnConfiguration": {},
            "additionalLinkedServiceNames": [],
            "linkedServiceName": "AzureStorageLinkedService"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using v1? Has your storage account enabled firewall?